# Android Studio internal error and unable to obtain result of 'adb version'?

Tags: android

My Android Studio (v 1.5) has always worked perfectly until just recently when my laptop shut down without a warning.

After rebooting, when I relaunched AS, an `internal IDE error occurred` message popped up but whenever I tried to click on it nothing happens, and suddenly there are tons of errors in my code even when it used to work perfectly fine before (lots of red underlines, mostly `'Cannot resolve'` errors).

I have tried:

- restarting AS several times
- closing and reopening the project
- cleaning and rebuilding the project
- manipulating the `idea.properties` file by adding a new line at the end as 
  commonly suggested in the other solutions I've found (although for some reason I couldn't overwrite the file)
- reinstalling Android Studio and on the first launch it gave me the `'unable to obtain result of adb version'`
- I ran `adb version` in the cmd and it responded instantly with the ff:

`Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision 09a0d98bebce-android`

I'm suspecting the spontaneous shut down must have broken something, but I'm not sure what. Are there any more possible solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by:

- `File` > `Invalidate Caches/Restart`
- Click `Invalidate and Restart`

After AS rebooted the errors are gone and the device I have plugged in for USB debugging is also detected. Not sure how this fixed it, but there you go.